# does it have a name : $\prod\left(1-x_i\right)$

Tags: polynomials

I want to know whether there is a formula or theorem on the expansion of this expression:
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-x_i\right).
$$
I only know the bionomial theorem and multinomiol theorem, but this one seems not those cases.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a special case of Vieta's formulas $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n (z-x_i)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^ke_k(x_1,\cdots,x_n)z^{n-k}$ with $z=1$.

Comment: A formula so familiar that most mathematicians even forget it has a name! :)

Comment: Got it. Thanks.